# WordPress редирект

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Сайт на вордпресе. В корневой директории разместил скрипт, который хочу открыть по ссылке адрес_сайта/скрипт.php

Но каждый раз происходит редирект на главную страницу сайта и скрипт не выполняется.

Содержимое htaccess

```
# Force HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_reporting 2047
php_value log_errors_max_len 0

<Files PHP_errors.log>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Не пользуюсь Apache, проверить не могу. Нижняя часть у вас стандартная. Проблема, думаю, в редиректе на https. Пишут, что надо так: "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]"

Comment: Вы скрипт открываете по ссылке с http или сразу `https://сайт.org/script.php` ?

Comment: сразу https и происходит редирект на https://сайт.org

Comment: Значит либо скрипт неправильно вызван/недоступен, либо так работает, либо сервер. Директива `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` исключает физически существующие файлы из обработки редиректа на индекс. Временно удали (переименуй) хтацесс и всё станет понятно.

Comment: @SeVlad так это стандартная директива, при ней свои скрипты работают. Скорее всего, у него плагины или тема переадресуют. Либо сам скрипт, да...

Comment: Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную, в тестовый скрипт вставьте одну строку `echo 'hi'` и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: @KAGGDesign так я я именно о том, что стандартная и скрипты работают. Проверка через временное удаление покажет где ошибка.